# Is there something similar to ARCore's anchor and pose in any other AR library

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, arcore

I wanna build measurement app for Android and iOS using Unity.  Can some one guide me through as it is my final year project and I am confused what to use that will work on both Android and iOS for all devices.

Answer (score 1):

> I am confused what to use that will work on both android and ios for all devices.

This is not a very reasonable thing to ask. You can deploy your applications to iOS and Android with both ARCore and Vuforia. However, not every device can run ARCore or Vuforia. There is a list of supported devices for both of them.

For the task you want to implement you need to use `Vuforia Fusion`. [Here](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/vuforia-fusion-supported-devices.html) is the list of devices that support `Vuforia Fusion`. On top of that these devices should fulfill certain requirements such as having minimum iOS 9+.

For ARCore the list is like [this](https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices) and ARCore also has requirements specific to devices. However, it is easy to say Vuforia supports more devices than ARCore. Therefore, Vuforia is used more in such applications recently but this might change in the future. I prefer ARCore over Vuforia because of the flexibility it provides to developers.

Since this is your final year project i would recommend doing a thorough AR SDK research first and then decide with which one to start. There might be other SDKs which might be better for the task in hand. Good luck!